# Show div element after reCaptcha validation

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I am using [Googles reCaptcha API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) for form validation.

I have opted to have the `submit` button show once the validation has been complete by using a little bit of JS.

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = '6LerNA0UAAAAAEReb9rS5JXjtvNSYlMjKiocUv_O';

    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){
        //show submit button
        echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
            function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("logDiv").style.visibility="visible";
            }
        </script>';             
    }
    else{           // stay hidden
        '<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
            function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("logDiv").style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        </script>'; 
    }
}
?>
<div id='logDiv' style='visibility:hidden')
<?php
echo $form->add('Login',array('type' => 'submit'));
?>
</div>
```

Currently, the solution isn't working; when the Captcha is validated the div remains hidden.

Is this a result of a syntax error or have a made a logical error?

What is the bug in my code?

Are there any more robust solutions?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the opening _div_ tag has a parenthesis at the end instead of a greater than - i.e. `<div id='logDiv' style='visibility:hidden')` - so changing it to `<div id='logDiv' style='visibility:hidden'>` will likely improve things...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a php condition to show the div? I think your JS isn´t working because you never call myFunction().

Try something like this but it will become complex over time and amount of code:

```
if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){

    $showButton = true;

}

......
if($showButton) { ?> 
<div id='logDiv' style='visibility:hidden'
<?php echo $form->add('Login',array('type' => 'submit'));
?> </div> <?php }

......
```

Or a simple Solution:

```
if(is_bool($data -> success) && $data -> success){

    echo '<div id="logDiv">'.$form->add('Login',array('type' => 'submit')).'</div>';

}
```

Echo the HTML Elements only if validition was successful otherwise simply dont ouput any HTML for the Div.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: As you know PHP is server side, so once the page is loaded nothing executed on the page will change anything...that is why JS is needed.

Comment: I dont unterstand what you try to  
achieve? You said the div schould be appear if validition was successfull. Simply echo the HTML String with PHP and the Div will appear if reCaptcha return success